# ASP NET 5 Identity role base authentication with custom or existing database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to create Role based security inheriting from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` that can be used with many different databases by just changing the CustomUser class if need be. I don't want 5 tables to be created through Entity Framework.

I created a dummy project that has all the code in it from the off and have been trying to understand the workings of the security by doing that.

I am stuck with the `CustomUserManager` though and how it is meant to operate in the account controller - there seems to be a lot of stuff I don't want in the pre-built project like the below:

```
private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
private readonly ISmsSender _smsSender;
```

Is the above really necessary, I want the first installment to literally just operate as role based security with my own password hasher.

Could someone give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

**My Code:**

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<CustomUser, CustomUserRole>();
        // tell the application to add mvc
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

**custom identity code**

```
        public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<CustomUserRole>
            {
                public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<CustomUserRole> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<CustomUserRole> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<CustomUserRole>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<CustomUserRole>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<CustomUserRole>> logger, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger, contextAccessor)
                {

                }
            }
            public class CustomUser
            {
                public Guid Id { get; set; }
                public string UserName { get; set; }
                public string FirstName { get; set; }
                public string LastName { get; set; }
                public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
                public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
            }

            public class CustomUserStore : IUserStore<CustomUser>
            {
                private readonly string connectionString;

                public CustomUserStore(string connectionString)
                {
                    this.connectionString = connectionString;
                }

                public CustomUserStore()
                {
                    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ConnectionString;
                }

                public void Dispose()
                {

                }

                public Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(CustomUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                {
                    user.PasswordHash = PasswordStorage.CreateHash(user.PasswordHash);
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                        {
                            connection.Open();
                            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("CreateUser", connection))
                            {
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.UserName);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", user.PasswordHash);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
    // all other methods are similar but removed for brevity sake
            }
public class CustomUserRole { }
public class CustomUserRoleStore : IRoleStore<CustomUserRole>
{
public Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(CustomUserRole role, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
// all the other methods are the same as I'm not sure what to put in them, if anything
}
```

Comment: You should also register your `CustomUserManager` in `Startup.cs`, might this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, will be needed and have added to my code. The contents of that link looks a lot more complicated than what I'm trying to achieve, sure will be useful though =)

Comment: You're welcome, you can always simplify it, or just derive from existing `UserStore` and simply override what do you want.